# If the premise of one's own question is badly mistaken, is it useful for it to remain open/visible?

Tags: discussion, closing-questions

I asked [this question](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/q/12937/12068) and have since come to the conclusion that the book I'm reading, which this was based on, is not particulary helpful if it doesn't even use basic terminology correctly. While I think the question was valid and meets the guidelines, I'm not seeking further answers and I'm not sure how useful it is for the question to remain up if the original premise is badly mistaken.

What precedents are there with similar posts in the past?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always answer the question yourself, and you can also select your own answer as the marked answer. This is quite useful if your question is flawed - you've done some research, come to the appropriate conclusion, and now you have an answer for your own question.

Answer (score 2):

I think the specific question is perfectly clear as is, and I will try to get around to answering it later.

[In general, it's discouraged to delete questions that have been answered, but you can delete unanswered questions.](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)